# CSS: How to change font color for a specific disabled field?

Tags: html, css, disabled-input

I found several topic about how to change all disabled fields's font-color by using the next code:

```
input[disabled=disabled] {
 /* your style */
 color: #fff !important;
}
```

But I have several disabled fields and I would like to change only the targeted field's color. So how can I add a targeting by ID to this script? Thank you for your help!

Comment: add a class to the one you want to style and use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the `input` selector for your `ID`:

```css
#thisOne[disabled=disabled] {
 color: #fff !important;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="thisOne" disabled="disabled" value="Lorem ipsum">

<input id="notThisOne" disabled="disabled" value="Lorem ipsum">
```

A class would probably make more sense so that you can reuse the styles:

```css
.these[disabled=disabled] {
 color: #fff !important;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="these" disabled="disabled" value="Lorem ipsum">
<input class="these" disabled="disabled" value="Lorem ipsum">

<input class="notThese" disabled="disabled" value="Lorem ipsum">
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I am sure your code works, but probably I am missing something. I am using the next code: <style  type="text/css">
input#MyFieldID[disabled=disabled] {color: red !important;}</style> I am trying to change the font color of a input field. I tryed with the class too like .myclass[disabled=disabled]... but still not works. Do u have any suggestion what can be wrong?

Comment: I would have to see your html. Can you create a simple example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I am using sharepoint so IDs are very disgusting autogenerated. I am using press F12+click on the textbox to find the correct ID. I added here the html of the textbox and my CSS code. Thank you very much for your help and sry for the trouble. https://jsfiddle.net/tm7otm8L/

Comment: Your id contains a dollar sign (`$`). You need to escape this in the selector with a back slash (`\ `). Also, because your `disabled` attribute has an empty value, you should change the selector from `[disabled=disabled]` to just `[disabled]`. I've updated your example: https://jsfiddle.net/tm7otm8L/1/