# I want to change the font color of a disabled input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to change the font color of V1. It's a disabled input and I want to make it darker. How can I do this for Chrome?

[image]

My HTML code is;

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="30" class="w-100-p"
                        ngClass.gt-xs="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Versiyon</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="Revision" type="text">
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Mind you, it's a reactive form so, my TS code is:

```
    Revision: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525249/css-how-to-change-font-color-for-a-specific-disabled-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: How to change font color for a specific disabled field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525249/css-how-to-change-font-color-for-a-specific-disabled-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this CSS class in your styles.scss file :

**For label**

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-disabled.mat-form-field-label {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.6)!important;
}
```

**For input value**

```
.mat-form-field-type-mat-native-select.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-infix::after, .mat-input-element:disabled {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1)!important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but the above answer did not work for me. This did. I put it in the actual component .css file, not styles.scss. My mat-form-field is in a custom component with appearance="outline".

Yes, I know ng-deep is depreciated, but it still works. Bite me.

For the selected value:

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-select-disabled .mat-select-value {
  color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
}
```

For the label (important tag is necessary):

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled label {
  color: rgb(43, 43, 43) !important;
}
```